# Routing Android application

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in an android development so I need help.

I'm working on android application which let user input locations on a map and the application make a routing to these locations based on the traffic and which location is close to another. This application aims to reduce the time of driving. I don't know what are the APIs I need. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use Google maps api.

Refer these,

http://javapapers.com/android/draw-path-on-google-maps-android-api/

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/